# What are the pros and cons of Zip Chain Actuators in robotics?

Tags: design, actuator, mechanical-engineering

Well, I just found out about these Zipper Chain Linear Actuators, but I couldn't find much information comparing these types to other types of actuators.

For example, what is the performance of Zip Chain Actuators compared to Linear Screw Actuators?

[image]

[image]

Of course, these are industrial level types of linear actuators, but you could make then out of 3D printing parts and achieve "good enough" capabilities.

[image]

[image]

Comment: a quick search returned this hit ... https://www.ustsubaki.com/blog/about-zip-chain-actuators/ ... you can ask questions interactively

Comment: Is this really worth a bounty? It's an alternative. You can compare datasheets and it's an option like any other.

Comment: I'm afraid that questions which ask about the Pros/cons or Advantages/disadvantages are effectively opinion polls, which are [discouraged on stack exchange](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/). We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of advantages & disadvantages for different options are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Tully's answer is great, but I just wanted to provide some examples.

Most linear actuators need a fair amount of collapsed height.  The ratio of length when extended to collapsed is usually around 2:1.  For example in the lead-screw based actuators in your question.

Of course, you can do better with a telescoping mechanism.  For example this telescoping ladder.  The ratio of extension to collapsed heights for this ladder is about 4.5:1.
[image: Telescoping Ladder]

However, a zipper mast is similar to a tape measure, where you can achieve a huge extension relative to a very small collapsed height.  The extension ratio of this tape measure is about 64:1.
[image: Standard tape measure]

For stability, the zipper mast is usually constructed from 2 or more "tape measure" like things, that zipper or interlock together.  Because the trade-off for this huge extension ratio is stability.  Also, I believe zipper masts are best at transmitting force in the extension direction.  They are very weak in other directions.  For example, you shouldn't use them horizontally.

One awesome application for a zipper mast is a retractable camera mast on a robot.  For example this demonstration on a PackBot.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TFvwp5vReSw
It would be difficult to achieve such an large height extension with any other type of mechanism because they would require a large stalk on the robot, even when retracted.

Only you can determine the right type of linear actuator and what is "good enough" for your application.

Answer (score 3):

The primary feature of a zip chain actuator is that it does not need extra depth to retract into. A standard linear actuator has a slider that will travel back behind the point of actuation. It will often need as much space behind the actuating surface as in front for its range of motion.

Whereas a zip chain actuator moves the volume to the side or other directions to allow you to have a lower profile actuator housing for a larger displacement distance.

There are other trade-offs, such as stiffness, precision, and other things that may vary between the different actuators that you might choose.

Comment: @fulano I see that you added a bounty on this question. Is there more that you want than is covered in my answer?